# This file is in a location outside your local network

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-7

If I launch my application from one network folder, I *don't* get a dialog.

However, if I copy my application to a different network folder, and try to launch it, I get the **"Open File - Security Warning"** dialog displayed below:

[image: Open File - Security Warning]

If you Google:

- [Open File - Security Warning dialog box](https://www.google.com/search?q=Open%20File%20-%20Security%20Warning%20dialog%20box&oq=Open%20File%20-%20Security%20Warning%20dialog%20box) or
- [This file is in a location outside your local network](https://www.google.com/search?q=This%20file%20is%20in%20a%20location%20outside%20your%20local%20network&oq=This%20file%20is%20in%20a%20location%20outside%20your%20local%20network)

you'll come across pages that talk about Intranet versus Internet zones, registry edits, Group Policy changes, or even Microsoft Access.

I don't want to deal with any of that if possible.  I need the solution to work across 100's of computers that will be launching this application from the network, and I can't make a system change to each of those computers.

**1. Why am I getting that dialog if I launch from certain network folders but not others?**

**2. How can I prevent that dialog from popping up?**

*Please mention multiple possibilities if applicable.*

Comment: I'm getting this error when using DFS namespaces in 2012, and now all my network-hosted applications are throwing this error. Most of the solutions out there regarding adjusting the security zones in group policy are obsolete in Server 2012.

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into this problem myself while trying to open some JavaScript files on a development storage Azure blob which I have mapped as a drive in Windows Explorer, I fixed it by going to:

`Control Panel > Internet Options > Security`

Then selecting `Local intranet`, clicking on `Sites`, unchecking

`[ ] Automatically detect intranet network`

and checking both:

`[x] Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones` and

`[x] Include all network paths (UNCs)`.

Comment: My configuration was already set to this, but I was still getting the message. What worked for me was clicking the "Advanced" button and adding the network PC's IP address to the zone.

Comment: I don't see those options on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box. Are they for clients only?

Comment: @David, you probably have Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration enabled. I'm not recommending you to turn it off on your server, but if you decide to do so: [instructions on how to do it](http://serverfault.com/a/140497).

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra, wow, thanks that was exactly it. What an unexpected connection.

Comment: If you have local DNS resolution, it's also a good idea to add the local domain name to the sites. Why I had to do this, despite full AD-integration remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do this by adding the DNS domain to the list of intranet sites.

Using Mathijs's answer partially:

1. `Control Panel > Internet Options > Security` or run `inetcpl.cpl`
2. Click `Local intranet`
3. Click `Sites` Click `Advanced` Add the FQDN of the server or domain. For instance, add "contoso.corp" (without double quotes), which will actually add `*.contoso.corp`, "whitelisting" all hosts who's FQDN resolves to the suffix `contoso.corp`.  Otherwise, you can add a full FQDN of a given server.

In my case, I had created a shortcut to the logon script for my users who were using software VPN clients; which was `%userdnsdomain%\netlogon\login.bat`, so I added `contoso.corp` and no longer received the warning.

Comment: Makes sense but it's not working on server 2012 r2. Trying to access files on a pc on same domain. PC name is pc1.contoso.corp, added contoso.corp in security settings... pinging pc1 does resolves pc1.contoso.corp

Comment: Adding the IP worked for me. No extra symbols, just `192.168.0.x`. (On W10 at least.)

Answer (score 4):

To Mathijs

Control Panel > Internet Options > Security
Adding the IPs of the drives in the Advanced button ( of local intranet) worked for me.   Automatically detect intranet network is still on

Comment: If you want to use computer/server name instead of IP then use file://ComputerName.

Answer (score 4):

You can also take care of this issue with a group policy.

I made a GPO called **Trusted Sites** and configured as follows.

*Computer Configuration -> Administration Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page*

On the security page, enable both of these:
**Intranet Sites: Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones

Intranet Sites: include all network paths (UNCs)**

The after a couple minutes, on the server having the issue, open a command prompt and run **gpupdate**  (no need to force this one).

Answer (score -8):

if you are the administrator of where you are working and you are extremely sure that applications (self written ones) are safe to launch. 
what you can do on win7 and win8 machines is go to 
Control Panel > User Accounts > Change User Account Control Settings and select "Never notify".
This removes the 'extra step' when executing the file.

Comment: that is not a solution

Comment: Disabling UAC is fundamentally dangerous and is bad practice. Only do this as an absolute last resort.. i.e. the application is critical and cannot run with UAC enabled or be modified to allow use whilst UAC is enabled.